# How can I change the pixel value range in an image?

Tags: image, matlab, range, scale, image-manipulation

I have grayscale images with values in the range [0-65533]. I've never see this before. What is this range?

I want to scale the values to the range [0-1200]. I tried the `imadjust` function but it does not work because this function required values between 0.0 and 1.0 only.

How can I use `imadjust` to scale these values properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That range of values suggest that your grayscale image contains unsigned 16-bit integers, i.e. it is of type [`uint16`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint16.html) (integer values from 0 to 65535). The documentation for [`imadjust`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imadjust.html) states that it supports images of this type, but it's still a little tricky to get the results you want.

Regardless of the image type, the contrast limits are always expected to be in the range `[0 1]`. This will require you to rescale them yourself by dividing by `65535`:

```
scaledImage = imadjust(uint16(inputImage), [0 65533]./65535, [0 1200]./65535);
```

Note that I also added the conversion `uint16(...)` just to make absolutely sure the input image is that type when passed to `imadjust`. If your input image happened to be converted to type [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) first, `imadjust` would expect the values to be in the range `[0 1]` for the image as well, which would give you an incorrect output in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just do something like this:

```matlab
newimage=1200.*oldimage./65533;
```

Comment: If the image is an integer type (i.e. `uint16`) this will likely lead to saturations/overflows.

Comment: Yes it is uint16 .. is this mean the image will be better?